# Load html in a webview from res/raw based on locale

Tags: android, android-webview, android-resources

using this code

```
WebView wvChangelog = (WebView) alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.wv_changelog);
wvChangelog.loadUrl("file:///android_res/raw/changelog");
```

I am able to load and show a html file from the `res/raw` folder, what I need to do is to load files from respected locale folders `eg raw/changelog , raw-de/changelog, raw-fa/chenglog` I believe the same snippet should work, but it only loads the main file (located in `raw` folder). although other locale related stuff in the same context (eg the title string loaded by getString(R.string.title) is respecting the locale.

Am I missing something here?

also I'm aware of `InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.filename);` but as you can see the WebView does not accept Input Stream and I have to comeup with a `file:///android_res...` type

Comment: Apparently there is no locale specific for the raw folder since it is not tracked liked the strings. You can either just check the user current locale and go from there.

Comment: but the raw folder is under `res` and everything under `res` is in the R class, and R class is supposed to be locale aware, AFAIK. also if I give hard code address of `file:///android_res/raw-de/changelog` I will get an error showing that android has some idea about this files being locale specific

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by creating multiple raw folders. Then to load each one specifically according to the language , That's the phone's language has to be changed, Settings >> Language and Input. Then it will choose the files accordingly.[image]